# Power series by algebraic numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, power-series

Let $\alpha$ be an algebraic number and $\beta$ be one of its algebraic conjugate. Suppose $|\alpha|, |\beta| > 1$.

Let $P_i(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be a sequence of polynomials with rational coefficients.

Suppose $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{P_i(\alpha)}{\alpha^i} \in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ so that we can write $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{P_i(\alpha)}{\alpha^i} = Q(\alpha)$ for some $Q(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Then depending on the choice of $\alpha, \beta, P_i(x)$, the following would or would not hold:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{P_i(\beta)}{\beta^i} = Q(\beta).$$

I know that if the sum only has finitely many terms, then applying the "obvious" field isomorphism $(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ on the both sides of 
$\sum_{i=1}^{N} \dfrac{P_i(\alpha)}{\alpha^i} = Q(\alpha)$ we can have the result. And I also find some examples so that the equality does not hold.

Is there any results/reference that is related to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: that sum doesn’t necessarily converge

Comment: Can you give an example where equality does not holds?

Comment: @Van yes but it does under the assumption $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{P_i(\alpha)}{\alpha^i} \in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$

Comment: @GreginGre Let $n$ be a positive integer. We can express every $x\in[0,1]$ by base-$n$ expansion $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{P_i}{n^i}$ where $P_i\in\{0, \ldots, n-1\}$. Similarly, we have non-integer base expansion, where the base and the digits used are not necessary in $\mathbb{N}$. Then an example can be found by choosing $\alpha$ as such a base, and consider $x\in[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$, and so on...